# Project Euler # 2 solution in PHP

Tags: php, numbers

I got the solution; however, I feel like the code is pretty awful.  This is within my first 50 hours using any programming language...please bear with me.

The Problem:

**Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.**

My Solution:

```
<?php

//if number is odd, returns false
function setOddsZero($n) {
    $test = ($n&1); //0 = even, 1 = odd
    if($test == 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $n = $n;
    }
}


$numbers=array(1,);
for($i>0; $i<=100; $i++) {
$numbers[$i] += (($numbers[$i-2])+($numbers[$i-1]));
  if (($numbers[$i]) >= 4000000) {
      echo $total;
      die;
  } else {
      if((setOddsZero($numbers[$i]))===false) {
          $total += 0;
      }else {
          $total += $numbers[$i];
      }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: setOddsZero needs a better name like isOdd

Comment: why do you += 0 if odd is false?

Comment: @dqhendricks, thanks for the helpful feedback. The array ends up cancelling, because i initiate the for loop only for `$i>0`, so the '1' in the array doesn't do anything.  the +=0 was just a poor statement.  Also, please excuse the tabs...first post here.

Cheers :)

Comment: Why are you asking here? Euler has a solution for almost all problems with a clear explanation and code. There's also a forum with other people's code on euler. And that's a feature of it, you can compare how clever you are at solving problems ;)

Comment: Didn't the fibonacci sequence start with `1, 1` traditionally?

Comment: stack = better community

Comment: @vzwick, I believe you are correct, sir.

Comment: @php_newb_88 i don't think the for loop initialization works quite the way you expect it to ... the first part of a `for` loop definition initializes the counter variable.Your `$i > 0` yields `false`, which I guess is being duck-typed into `0` at the first iteration. Frankly, I'm pretty surprised that this thing works at all. You'll wanna use `for ($i = 1 …`.

Comment: Btw: +1 for entertaining me with funny PHP quirks.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this question.

Comment: @vzwick, I figured at least someone else would get a chuckle from `$total += 0` ! :)

I must admit; all other quirks were unintentional.

Comment: with the current method, on your first two iterations, some of the array items referenced in trying to get the next Fibonacci number are undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fibos = array(1,2);
$sum_of_evens = 0;

while ($fibos[1] < 4000000)
{
    $fibos []= array_shift($fibos) + $fibos[0];
    $sum_of_evens += ($fibos[1] & 1 == 0) ? $fibos[1] : 0;
}

echo $sum_of_evens;
```

---

Less stack-pushy-shify (and thus more efficient) approach, as suggested by [meze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265712/meze):

```
$prevprev = 1;
$prev = 2;
$sum_of_evens = 0;

while ($prev < 4000000)
{
    list($prevprev, $prev) = array($prev, ($prevprev + $prev));
    $sum_of_evens += ($prev & 1 == 0) ? $prev : 0;
}
```

---

*Edit: Modified the code to use `& 1` instead of `% 2`, cf. [this thread at devshed](http://forums.devshed.com/software-design-43/quick-algorithm-to-determine-odd-even-numbers-29843.html).*

Comment: Nice, wasn't aware of the array_shift function

Comment: This is an inefficient solution ;s

Comment: @meze From the "number of operations required" perspective, you're probably right. But it's concise. Shifting values by hand like `$prevprev = $prev; $prev = $current` just feels really awkward to me when using a higher level language.

Comment: Then you could replace it with `list ($prevprev, $prev) = array($prev, $current);`

Comment: @meze Personally, I hate `list()` (sersiously, assigning values to something that looks like a function call? Meh!), you're right though. Updated the answer to reflect your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution using a for loop:

```
$a = 0;
$b = 1;
$p = 0;
$limit = 4000000;

for($i=0; $p < $limit; $i++) {
    $sum = $a+$b;
    $a = $b;
    $b = $sum;

    // Checks if $a is a multiple of 2
    if($a%2 == 0) {
        $p += $a;
    }
}
echo $p;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to remember all the numbers.

```
$num0 = 1;
$num1 = 1;
$num2 = 0;
$odd = 0;
do
{
    //The way you count recurents in cycles
    $num2 = $num1 + $num0;

    $num0 = $num1;
    $num1 = $num2;

    //Classic check wheter the number is odd o even
    if($num2 % 2 == 1)
        $odd++;
} while($num2 < 4000000);
```

Comment: much neater. The odd check is much cleaner too.

Comment: *find the sum of the even-valued terms* vs. `$odd++` doesn't seem right ... Should be `$odd += $num2`, also your even/odd check is borked, should be `($num2 % 2) == 0`

Comment: However, output doesn't result in the solution.

cheers :)

Comment: The mod call is a bad idea. Project euler is usually about avoiding divisions. An alternative to it's use might be $odd != $odd

Answer (score -4):

PHP is a poorly designed language.  I guess that you're learning it because you want to work on server side web programming.  Check out rails and django instead.